# how to mark pages as visited in chrome extensions?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

What I want to do is to execute a script on an active tab only when it's Highlighted and that script wasn't executed before on that page.

- The execution is when the tab is highlighted.
- The execution must be only once for the page unless if it was refreshed.
- If the page was refreshed or the link(location) of the tab was changed then I must execute the script the next time the tab is highlighted.

What I'm basically thinking of doing after surfing the internet is to store a variable in the page window and check it every time.

At first i tried this

```
chrome.tabs.onHighlighted.addListener(function(){
    var query = { active: true, currentWindow: true };
    chrome.tabs.query(query, function(tabs) {
        chrome.windows.get(tabs[0].windowId, function(window){
            if(!window.fbaVisitedPage){
                window.fbaVisitedPage=true;
                //execute script here only once per page.
            }
        });
    });
});
```

but it didn't work, so I tried to use the default `window` variable

```
chrome.tabs.onHighlighted.addListener(function(){
    var query = { active: true, currentWindow: true };
    chrome.tabs.query(query, function(tabs) {
        chrome.windows.get(tabs[0].windowId, function(win){//change is here
            if(!window.fbaVisitedPage){
                window.fbaVisitedPage=true;
                //execute script here only once per page.
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The problem in the second code is that the variable `window.fbaVisitedPage` is still defined even after I refresh the page. I was expecting the variable `window.fbaVisitedPage` to become undefined after the page is refreshed but that didn't happened.

How can I solve this problem? How can I mark a page as `visited` and unmark it if the page was reloaded or it's `location' was changed?

Comment: The background page is a separate hidden page with its own DOM so `window` refers to that useless DOM, not to the web page. See also [the architecture overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch). You need to rework the code e.g. set the window property inside a content script.

Comment: @wOxxOm Works like a charm. If you answered my question I'll accept your answer. thanks.